# GWTP: Reveal unauthorizedPlaceRequest after successful login

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

When a user is not logged in and navigates to !/someRestrictedPlace he is is navigated due to the LoggedInGatekeeper to the login page. After successful login I want that the user will be redirected to !/someRestrictedPlace

What I did is create a DefaultPlaceManagerImpl extends PlaceManagerImpl then I use the following method:

```
@Override

public void revealUnauthorizedPlace(String unauthorizedHistoryToken) {

       revealPlace(unauthorizedPlaceRequest, true);

}
```

**Is this the way to do it, because the comments in DefaultPlaceManage says that this would create an infinite loop?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

In my PlaceManager I redirect to LoginPresenter but by #someRestrictedPlace/login

```
public void revealUnauthorizedPlace(String unauthorizedHistoryToken) 
{
     revealRelativePlace(new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.login));
}
```

In my LoginPresenter after successful login

```
if (placeManager.getHierarchyDepth() > 1)
    placeManager.revealRelativePlace(-1);
else
    placeManager.revealPlace(...some default place..., true);
```

Comment: Your solution does not work with RootPlace tokens. Because placeManager.getHierarchyDepth() is always 1

Comment: What are "RootPlace tokens"? If you navigate to url without "#" PlaceManager will redirect to some default place. If this place will be unauthorized revealUnautjorizedPlace method will redirect to #someDefault/login. This activates LoginPresenter with user/password fields (or something else to login). In LoginPresenter after successful login you check hierarhyDepth and decide where to redirect next.